# Helm find-file foreground face for interactive current directory in minibuffer

Tags: spacemacs, helm, faces, interactive

I'm using Spacemacs with

```
$ emacs --version
> GNU Emacs 24.5.1
```

On OSX 10.10.5

Using `C-x C-f` to find files shows a minibuffer like:
[image: minibuffer]

I have been able to get rid of the ugly green foreground color for highlighting the matching results by changing the face with:

```
M-x set-face-foreground
```

then searching for helm and selecting `helm-match`

But I can't seem to find the correct face to modify to change the current directory displayed at the top. In the image, it's the `Find file: /` bit I'm talking about.

Using 'C-c C-x =' when in the minibuffer in this mode only brings up a cursor position, but no information about the face.

So my questions are:

1) What is this particular face I need to modify?

2) More generally, how would I find out which face this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`M-x list-faces-display`** is your friend.

It shows you all faces currently defined. And you can click on a face name to open Customize for that face.

---

If you use library [Face-Menu+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FaceMenuPlus) (code: [`facemenu+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/facemenu%2b.el)) then `list-faces-display` is even more useful.  If you click the sample text shown for a given face then:

- If the region is active and non-empty in the buffer that was current before you used `M-x list-faces-display` then the face you click is applied to the text in that region.
- Otherwise, the face whose sample you clicked is applied to new text that you enter (in the buffer that was current before you used `M-x list-faces-display`).

IOW, `list-faces-display` also gives you a *WYSIWYG way to apply a face*, in addition to a WYSIWYG way to edit (customize) a face.

---

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then these kinds of things are even easier. You can skip using `list-faces-display` altogether, because commands that ask for a face name show the completion candidates using their faces (WYSIWYG).  [Description and screenshots](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Candidates_with_Text_Properties).

Comment: Thanks a ton. Lots of good information here. I'm going to accept this answer because I did use `list-faces-display` to resolve the issue. But it took some digging to id the face I needed. For future reference, the face is `mini-buffer-prompt`. Any tips on being able to discover the face are still appreciated --- I think it being in the minibuffer (and only visible when you're in the midst of running a command) made grabbing that info tricky.

Comment: It's probably `minibuffer-prompt`, not `mini-buffer-prompt`. Yes, it's generally more difficult to get info on stuff that is in the minibuffer. The good news is that such stuff usually has a name that starts with or contains `"minibuffer"`. For example, to find out about keys bound in the minibuffer keymaps, you can use [`help-fns+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el) command `describe-keymap` (`C-h M-k`) for the keymaps whose names start with `minibuffer-`.

Comment: Right you are, `minibuffer-prompt`